# IIS File Permissions

Tags: iis, windows-server-2003, file-permissions

I have an app which I'm trying to restrict permissions to while I'm doing maintenance.  I use windows file permissions and remove access to the dll file the app runs from for all non admin accounts, ie:

cacls "%DLL_LOC%" /E /R BUILTIN\Users

and then I recycle the application pool (which was working on my dev environment to lockout users):

cscript c:\windows\system32\iisapp.vbs /a "DefaultAppPool" /r

But no luck as anybody can still access the dll and the app.

Any further ideas are appreciated as I haven't gotten the permissions to consistently be applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a couple of illfated attempts at trying to block network ports for a workaround and restarting the machine two or three times the users are blocked.

Sorry for the simple restart fix XP.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the file you are editing is not [inheriting its permissions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318754) from the folder above.

Comment: Checked that and not inheriting from above (actually I think I had to disable inheritance to be able to my changes manually the first time).